# Is there a name of `skew unitary matrix'

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

As we know, a matrix $U$ is called unitary if
\begin{equation*}
U^*U=UU^*=I,
\end{equation*}
i.e.
\begin{equation*}
U^{-1}=U^*
\end{equation*}
where $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $U$ and $I$ is the identity matrix.

What the name of the matrix $U$ which satisfies
\begin{equation*}
U^*U=UU^*=-I?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Isn't $U^*U$ positive semdefinite?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: So the answer is: it's called the $0\times 0$ identity matrix $I_0\in\Bbb C^{0\times 0}$. $\ddot\smile$.